# Add audio bulk in the video file

Tags: video

Good Day. I have 1000 Video files ( without Audio ) I want to add audio in the video. same audio for all the videos. Any software suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

the Linux script should be

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in /Videos/*; do
    ffmpeg -i $filename -i <audio_file> -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest OutputWithAudio_$filename
done
```

Comment: Not just linux, that will work on macs and Windows computers with bash installed.

Answer (score 0):

[Ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) is by far the best software for this kind of thing. Here's the Powershell version for windows to add to @xer-rex's answer:

```
get-childItems "c:\path\to\videos\folder\"|%{
  ffmpeg -i $filename -i <audio_file> -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest ("OutputWithAudio_" + $_.name)
}
```